# Catch exception in ctypes based on C-exit code

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am calling a shared-library written in `C` from `Python/numpy` using `ctypes`. This works fantastic, however, when the `exit` function is used in `C` some unexpected results occur in `iPython`.

Consider the following example, where the first item of an array "A" is modified in `C`. If the value is negative an exception should be raised.

The `C`-code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

extern void cfun(double* A)
{

  // raise exception if A[0]<0.0
  if ( A[0]<0.0 ) {
    printf("Negative value of A[0] encountered\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // change "A[0]" to it's square
  A[0] = pow(A[0],2);

}
```

Which is compiled using

```
gcc -c -fPIC fun.c
gcc -shared -o test.so fun.o
```

The wrapping `Python`-code:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

# include shared library
lib = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")

# link to C-program, including input-typing
cfun          = lib.cfun
cfun.restype  = None
cfun.argtypes = [ np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ctypes.c_double,flags="C_CONTIGUOUS") ]

# simple example
A = np.arange((5),dtype='float')+2.
cfun(A)
print A
# expected output: [ 4.  3.  4.  5.  6.]

# simple example
A[0] = -10.0
cfun(A)
print A
# expected output: exception, no output from "print A"
```

When I run this code from the command-line the program does what it should. The output:

```
[ 4.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
Negative value of A[0] encountered
```

However when I run the python function from `iPython`

- the wanted behavior is that some kind of exception is raised,
- the current behavior is that when the error is encountered also `iPython` exists.

I believe the most elegant solution is to introduce an error-stream as (return) argument signaling the success or failure. However I really would like to avoid this. I use an extensive `C`-code. Introducing an error-stream would overly complicate the dependency between all the functions.

Please help!

Comment: `exit` terminates your program. If your program is the Python interpreter, then it terminates the Python interpreter. If you don't want this, don't call `exit`

Comment: is there no way catch the ``exit`` in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` calles the system's exit function and terminates the process running, in your case ipython. The way error handling is done in C is by setting some global error variable and returning a status flag

```
#include <math.h>

char *error_string;

extern char* get_error_string() {
    return error_string;
}

extern int cfun(double* A)
{
  // raise exception if A[0]<0.0
  if ( A[0]<0.0 ) {
    error_string = "Negative value of A[0] encountered\n";
    return -1;
  }

  // change "A[0]" to it's square
  A[0] = pow(A[0],2);
  return 0;
}
```

and in Python test for errors:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

# include shared library
lib = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")

# link to C-program, including input-typing
get_error          = lib.get_error
get_error.restype  = ctypes.c_char_p
get_error.argtypes = []

def c_error_wrapper(func):
    def method(*args):
        status = func(*args)
        if status<0:
            raise RuntimeError(get_error())
    return method

# link to C-program, including input-typing
cfun          = lib.cfun
cfun.restype  = ctypes.c_int
cfun.argtypes = [ np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ctypes.c_double,flags="C_CONTIGUOUS") ]

cfun = c_error_wrapper(cfun)

# simple example
A = np.arange((5),dtype='float')+2.
cfun(A)
print A
# expected output: [ 4.  3.  4.  5.  6.]

# simple example
A[0] = -10.0
cfun(A)
print A
# expected output: exception, no output from "print A"
```

Comment: Thanks! Although... I was really hoping to avoid this additional "stream". I really like the crude behavior of the system exit, since it does exactly what I want to do: stop, but introduce no additional variables/arguments. This allows me to use the ``return`` for something else. Also, some of my functions are written in ``Fortran`` in which an additional header variable is needed for the error code.

Comment: `C` and `Fortran` have no concept for exception handling. And every language which have one, use a individual technique, so that cross-language exception handling is not possible.

Comment: You can set the error handler as [`cfun.errcheck`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.errcheck).